# manage activity back and forth

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to implement following approach when i move back and forth while traversing activities

`MainActivity` is the entry point activity. Menu inside this activity opens the `PreferenceActivity`

`PreferenceActivity` is and activity which shows preferences/settings and clicking it over one of 
the preferences will call `HelpActivity`

`HelpActivity` contains the help of application.
[image]

*Note : once i reach to `MainApplication` and if i press back i want to go out of the application.

i tried calling `finish()` after every intent i call but that ruled out the CASE #2

**update**

When i reach to `HelpActivity` in CASE #1 and press a button i want to go to the `MainActivity` and all the other Activities should wiped out

Comment: seems like there is no provision to control activity behavior in android

Answer (score 0):

Use this scenario. And let me know what happen.. (Only pseudo code actual may be different)

**MainActivity:**

```
1. startActivityForResult(PreferenceActivity);

2. onBackPressed()
  {
   finish();
  }
```

**PreferenceActivity:**

```
1. startActivityForResult(HelpActivity);

2. onActivityResult()
   {
    finish();
   }

3. onBackPressed()
   {
    finish();
   }
```

**HelpActivity:**

```
1. onBackPressed()
   {
    finish();
   }
```

Comment: Well i tried this but its not altering the typical behavior , it behaves like case 2 only

Comment: And what about in PreferenceActivity if you simple `finish()` after calling HelpActivity using `startActivity()`. ??

Comment: As i am calling intent using PreferenceScreen in xml so there is no way to call finish() in that i gues

Answer (score 0):

case #1:

MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
button add;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.youeLayout);
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonIdName);
    add.setOnClickListener(R.id.buttonIdName)

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent data = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PreferenceActivity.class);
    startActivity(data);
}
```

and the same code for the PreferenceActivity just change the onClick() method to the appropriate classes you want

in the helpActivity:
add the onBackPressed() method like this:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
            Intent youeIntentName = new Intent(HelpActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(youeIntentName);
}
```

case# 2 :

you don't need to change any thing when the user press back after he go from MainActivity to PreferenceActivity he will be back the MAinActivity and so on

Comment: Well in your case the whole path will get executed when i press back from HelpActivity after it reaches to MainActivity

Comment: in case#2 when press the back button it will put the active class in onPause() method first and to onStop() method after that in the onStop() method the activity will not close its invisible check the activity life cycle in this page :